# What is the name of the WiFi card size in the UX31E?

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, asus-laptop, zenbook

I am planning to upgrade the WiFi card in my 1st gen Zenbook UX31E from N to AC.

What is the name of the size of my Mini PCI-Express card?

[image: The card]

Comment: Its a Mini PCI-Express module.  Asus is suggesting basically the same part.

Comment: Yes, but I obviously cant upgrade it with a standard Mini PCI-Express card.

Comment: Your statement makes no sense. If the item installed in your hardware is a Mini PCI-Express product, then you can replace it, with a Mini PCI-Express product supported by the hardware. The replacement part has a generic item image.  The Asus replacement part has no information to determine if it is indeed a Mini PCI-Express card

Comment: Updated the question. It is a Mini PCI-Express card, but when I search for "Mini PCI-Express Card AC" I can only find whole and half sized card, not this specific size with only one screw.

Comment: I would almost guarantee the other screw is simply hidden.  Mini PCI-Express is a standard, there form factor is well defined, only ASUS can provided the require information about the replacement part.

Comment: According to this site: http://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_AW-NB086 it seems to be a non-standard connector.

Comment: Thank you, @JoshR! Looks like my Zenbook wont get upgraded then.

Comment: @JoshR - A non-standard PCIe card != mini PCIe card

Comment: @Ramhound Semi-true. It depends on the scope we're using to define "Mini PCI-E". The connector and bus probably fit the standard, and so the card is probably cross-compatible with other Mini PCI-E interfaces. The physical form factor on the other hand is not, which means that the motherboard/case is not designed to accept other Mini PCI-E cards.

Comment: You are correct. @Ramhound I should not have said a non-standard connector, more a non-standard form factor.

Comment: If that ZenBook looks like [this one](http://www.ski-epic.com/2012_asus_zenbook_ux31_disassembly_teardown), than it's not compatible with standard Half-mini PCI-E cards.

Comment: Lets just agree the original part isn't a mini PCI-E part.  The replacement unit is.  This mean the replacement part isn't compatible.

Comment: @week, correct, that's the very same model as mine.

Comment: I might be able to use a https://cdn.techship.se/uploads/images/168/kzb22_1.1353066230.jpg to force it to fit inside my Zenbook

Comment: But you would need to cut that PCB, because it's also a standard half-mini length. Or DIY :)

Comment: @week: was thinking of one of [these](http://www.exnetz.de/59-116-large/pcie-pci-e-express-x1-extender-riser-karte-flex-kabel.jpg) but was to lazy to find the image :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have a name. The card is custom made for the UX31 as [Wikidevi](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_AW-NB086) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191020204458/http://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_AW-NB086)) shows it.

Answer (score 0):

Half Mini PCI-E card made by AzureWave (AW-NB086) Qualcomm AR9485WB-EG.  It has MHF4 Female connectors so you need an adapter with that on one end and U.FL connectors on the other (found a few on Ebay coming from China).